# Applying a function across nested list containing matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix, nested, apply

This question is a successor to [Applying a function across nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453574/applying-a-function-across-nested-list). Whereas it deals with list of list of vectors, this one is concerned with list of list of matrices.

The input looks like

```
set.seed(42L)
input <- replicate(3, replicate(4, matrix(rnorm(25), nrow=5), simplify=FALSE), simplify=FALSE)
```

I want to calculate the **mean of the corresponding entries of the out-most list**. Of course I can use a for-loop, but there must be another way that is faster, conciser, and clearer?

```
result <- replicate(4, matrix(0, nrow=5, ncol=5), simplify=FALSE)
for (i in 1:3) {
    for (j in 1:4) {
        for (k in 1:5) {
            for (l in 1:5) {
                result[[j]][k, l] <- result[[j]][k, l] + input[[i]][[j]][k, l]
            }
        }
    }
}
result <- lapply(result, function(x) x / 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Reduce` function is your friend for doing element-wise operations across lists. The only other relatively tricky part is the nesting part (which requires two `lapply` calls - if you wanted the element-wise mean for each element `input`, we could have called `Reduce` immediately).

```r
lapply(seq_along(input[[1]]), FUN = function(i){
  Reduce("+", lapply(input, `[[`, i)) / length(input)
})
```

Comment: Your solution is correct. I have updated my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This would result in a 3D matrix instead of a list of 2D matrices, but it appears to be faster than the solution provided by @ClancyStats.

```
apply(aperm(array(unlist(input), c(5, 5, 4, 3)), c(3, 4, 1, 2)), c(1, 3, 4), mean)
```